# How to stop drawing a SpriteBatch animation in libgdx?

Tags: android, animation, libgdx

Hi I have a spritebatch animation in Libgdx.  It only plays once and when it is finished I want to stop drawing it so it doesn't appear on the screen.  I have a boolean that checks if it is still alive i.e. animating and it is set to false when the animation is finished using isAnimationFinished however it stays on the screen and I am not sure why even though a log print shows it changing to false on finish.  Does anyone have any idea why this is? Thanks for your help.  The following code is from my render method.

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // This cryptic line clears the screen.
     boolean alive = true;
     stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();           // #15
        currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, false);  // #16
        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.draw(menu, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        if (alive)
        spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame,50,50);
        if(walkAnimation.isAnimationFinished(stateTime))
        alive = false;
        System.out.println(alive);
        spriteBatch.end();
        stage.draw();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see is that you **always** declare a new boolean variable "alive" and set the alive to true at the beginning:

```
boolean alive = true;
```

and then all your drawing is happening and **after** all that you set alive to false if your animation is finished:

```
if(walkAnimation.isAnimationFinished(stateTime))
    alive = false;
```

==> That is too late, because after this you don't do anything anymore with this *local* variable.

---

You could for example check if "alive" should be true or false right at the beginning and set its value accordingly, like for example:

```
 boolean alive = true;
 if(walkAnimation.isAnimationFinished(stateTime)) {
    alive = false;
 }
 //your drawing code below..
```

alternatively you could make "alive" a field instead of a local variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out.  It was a stupid mistake I made.  I made my boolean variable global instead and it works fine now.